# Find file from class path or from resources using file name & get path of that file

Tags: java, resources, classpath

I want file path of file which is in sub folder in class path/resources.

I am getting file name as input param, on the basis of that name i need to find that file from resources/class path and get the path of that file. so i can send that path back requester.

i am having resource structure as:

```
src/main/resources
|_ templates
     |_ balance
          |_ bal_template.cls
     |_ summary
          |_ Summary_template.cls
```

and so on.
so ill get `bal_template.cls` name in input & based on name i want to find this file in class path and get its location/path like `/templates/balance/bal_template.cls` and send the path back.

i tried with

```
ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource("bal_template.cls");
```

But it gives `null` as i am passing only file name, to make it workable need to pass full path.

```
ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/templates/balance/bal_template.cls");
```

but i want solution in such way that ill get path by file name.
`String path = getPathByFileName(fileName);`
Please suggest

Comment: Your second example is almost correct;  just remove the `getClassLoader().` part.  It should be `ClassName.class.getResource("/templates/balance/bal_template.cls");`.

Comment: what will happen if i remove `getClassLoader()` @VGR

Comment: The argument to ClassLoader.getResource is always relative to the root of each classpath entry and must not start with a slash.  The argument to Class.getResource is relative to the class's package if it has no initial slash, but is relative to the root if it starts with a slash.  Also, Class.getResource will work in Java 9 and later when modules and modular encapsulation are in effect.  I recommend reading the documentation for each method.